# How can I know whether a sound card is present on my system or not?

Tags: soundcard

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome classic. Obviously playing the music shows there is a sound card present. But I've read that there might be multiple sound cards present on a single system.

How can I know how many sound cards are present on my system? Also, how can I know which all they are?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To detect your soundcard, use `sudo aplay -l` from the Terminal.

**Courtesy:**https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

Type in a terminal:

```
 hwinfo | grep sound.card_id
```

Comment: hwinfo is not avaiable in the default Ubuntu installation. It has to be manually installed by using `sudo apt-get install hwinfo`

Comment: can't even find it in the repos

Comment: what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: `hwinfo` is a nice tool but this grep outputs nothing

Comment: sudo  hwinfo | grep sound