Ubuntu 24.04 cannot see Realtek ALC892
After a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04, I have no sound. I had sound before with Ubuntu 20.04, and also when upgraded to 22.04. BTW, the upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 was botched, and so I had to do a clean install.
I cannot see the ALC892 in Settings->Sound->Output, but I can see it in alsamixer.
Maybe my system is too old? Or something is not right with pipewire? Would be great if someone can show me a workaround, thanks!
ALC892 does not show up in Settings->Sound->Output
ALC892 shows up in alsamixer as HDA Intel PCH

Will this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/844284/no-sound-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-realtek-alc892

Thanks for the suggestion @amar. I installed pulse audio volume control, which was mentioned in that post, and just with like the sound settings, I don't see my soundcard as an output device.

Run sudo aplay -l https://askubuntu.com/questions/140642/how-can-i-know-whether-a-sound-card-is-present-on-my-system-or-not

Thanks @amar Well, aplay -l lists the card I wanted to use, but somehow that card is not listed in Settings->Sound->Output: card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog] I suspect something is up with pipewire. At the moment, I don't know that well enough to troubleshoot it.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/how-to-understand-list-of-soundcards-meaning-of-mid-hdmi-pch

@amar. Finally working now! Weird that I was able to see and select my device in VLC, but not in Ubuntu sound settings.Then I realized the reason the device did not show up in Ubuntu sound settings was because my cable was plugged into the wrong port. As you had mentioned, aplay -l would list the devices, and mine was listed. Maybe the Ubuntu UI should have just said not plugged in instead of not showing it. Thanks for helping me to realize that things are really working!!!

I have the same issue with my TP-LINK wifi dongle that uses the generic rtl8821au driver. Every distro upgrade ends up with the same issue. The kernel upgrade breaks the compiled driver module, and it needs to be downloaded for the new kernel and recompiled. The trick is getting the correct driver from GitHub, which given the abundance of drivers, is not easy.
The one that did it for me is:
https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708
Just do
sudo git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git into /usr/src

cd into the /usr/src/8821au-20210708 directory, and run the installation script
sudo ./install-driver.sh

You won't even have to reboot. As soon as the installation ends, you'll start seeing networks appear in the networks widget.
